# Decoherence paper, incomprehensible claims

Tags: measurements, superposition, decoherence

I am reading the paper "The quantum-to-classical transition and decoherence"
by Maximilian Schlosshauer (https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.2635).
I doubt the most basic claims in this paper.

The story is as follows: an isolated microscopic system $S$ (Hilbert space $H_S$) is put into a superposition
$\phi=\phi_1+\phi_2$ of states $\phi_1,\phi_2\in H_S$ and then brought into
contact with an environment $E$ (Hilbert space $H_E$) which initially is in state $e\in H_E$.
Before interaction the composite system $(S,E)$ is in state
$$
\Phi=\phi\otimes e = \phi_1\otimes e+\phi_2\otimes e\in H_S\otimes H_E.
$$
Now an interaction between $S$ and $E$ takes place and it is claimed that this puts the combined system
$(S,E)$ into a state of the form
$$
\Psi = \phi_1\otimes e_1+\phi_2\otimes e_2\in H_S\otimes H_E
$$
(cited paper, equation (1), p2). This is surprising, since we do not know anything about the
interaction (no assumptions made).

I believe that such a principle cannot be maintained:
we can write $\phi$ in other ways as a superposition
$\phi=\psi_1+\psi_2$ and it must then follow that $\Psi$ is also of the form
$$
\Psi = \psi_1\otimes f_1 + \psi_2\otimes f_2\in H_S\otimes H_E,
$$
for some vectors $f_1,f_2\in H_E$.

In other words the vectors $e_1,e_2\in H_E$ have the following interesting property:
$$
\psi_1+\psi_2=\phi_1+\phi_2\ \Rightarrow\  
\exists f_1,f_2\in H_E:\thinspace 
\phi_1\otimes e_1+\phi_2\otimes e_2 = \psi_1\otimes f_1 + \psi_2\otimes f_2.
$$
We will now exhibit an example where such vectors $e_1,e_2$ do not exist.
Let $H_S=H_E=L^2([0,1])$. Then the tensor product $H_S\otimes H_E$ is isomorphic to the
Hilbert space $L^2([0,1]^2)$ with a canonical isomorphism mapping $f(x)\otimes g(y)$
to the function $f(x)g(y)\in L^2([0,1]^2)$.

Now let $\phi_1(x)=1$, $\phi_2(x)=x$, $\psi_1(x)=1-\sqrt x$ and $\psi_2(x)=x+\sqrt x$.
Then $\phi_1+\phi_2=\psi_1+\psi_2$ but there are no functions $e_1(y),e_2(y)\in H$
such that the function $\phi_1(x)e_1(y)+\phi_2(x)e_2(y)$ can be written in the form
$$
\phi_1(x)e_1(y)+\phi_2(x)e_2(y) = \psi_1(x)f_1(y)+\psi_2(x)f_2(y),
$$
for some functions $f_1,f_2\in H$ since this amounts to the equality
$$
e_1(y)+xe_2(y) = (1+\sqrt x)f_1(y)+(x-\sqrt x)f_2(y),
$$
for almost all $x,y\in[0,1]$. Simply evaluate the equality at enough different values of $x$
to obtain an overdetermined system of equations in $e_i(y),f_j(y)$ with no solution.
Clearly this same argument works if we replace $H=L^2([0,1])$ with a finite dimensional
Euclidean space of dimension at least 5.

Why is this not a problem?

Comment: From the paper, $S$ assumed to be two-dimensional. Thus, *any* state will be of the form $\phi_1\otimes e_1 + \phi_2\otimes e_2$, if $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ for a basis for $S$, which means the initial state must evolve into a state of that form. So whatever calculations you've done *can't* be a problem.

Comment: @march OK, thanks, I overlooked this, since it is not explicitly stated in the paper. If you make it an official answer it will be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the paper, the states that OP labels $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ correspond to the states $\lvert s_1\rangle$ and $\lvert s_2 \rangle$, which correspond to passage through one of two slits in a double-slit experiment. For that reason, the Hilbert space $S$ is two-dimensional, and so *any* state in the tensor product space of $S$ and $E$ can be written in the form
$$
\phi_1\otimes e_1 + \phi_2\otimes e_2\,,
$$
where $s_j$ are some arbitray states in $E$. In particular, the state after some time-evolution must be write-able in this way, so there can be no contradiction.

The issue with the OP's "counterexample" is that they are implicitly assuming that $S$ is of dimension greater than 2, because they are using the four states $\phi_1(x)=1$, $\phi_2(x)=x$, $\psi_1(x)=1-\sqrt x$, and $\psi_2(x)=x+\sqrt x$, which spans a space of dimension 3.

Comment: It should be noted that the paper is very confusing as a position variable x is postulated on the 2 dimensional space for S, see equation (3) and first line of p3 (the inner product  (x,s_i) is defined. This would make the Hilbert space H_S infinite dimensional.